# Can't connect to MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

Tags: mysql, sockets, centos

When I try to install mysql in my Centos, i try to key in the temporary password and it appear this error

```
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through 
socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (40)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following solutions:

**Method 1:**

**Check whether mysql service is running**

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

Try connecting now

**Method 2:**

**Try connecting to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`**

If you connect to `localhost`, it will use your socket connector, but if you connect to `127.0.0.1` the TCP/IP connector will be used.

Restart mysql and connect again.

**Method 3:**

**Edit file `my.cnf`** Locate the `my.cnf` file inside `/etc/` location

Edit/add following lines:

```
[mysqld]

socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 

[client]

socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Restart mysql and connect again.

***Edit after you shared your error:***

It seems like pid file or mysqld directory is missing `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`

**Create the directory `/var/run/mysqld` using**

```
mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld/
```

**Grant the permission to mysql**

```
chown mysql.mysql /var/run/mysqld/
```

**Restart the `mysqld`**

```
sudo service mysqld restart
```

Hope atleast one of these solutions works in your case!!

Comment: when i run this code sudo service mysqld start it appear tis error
"Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."

Comment: @YongJin can you try the updated solution, hopefully that works!!